# SCSS: How to select "::before" which have sibling with a specific class

Tags: html, css, scss-mixins, trumbowyg

I have been trying to select a `::before` element inside a `div` which have a sibling which specific class name (`trumbowyg-link-button`).

Here, how it look like:
[image]

**What I've tried**

```
.trumbowyg-button-group > button.trumbowyg-link-button {
  &:before {
    content: none !important;
  }
}
```

But unfortunate it's not working.
Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: you cannot as you have to select the parent element of the pseudo element

Comment: You can't do this. The `::before` pseudo-element belongs to the parent element.

Comment: And even if that wasn’t the issue, it would still the wrong way around - if you have `<parent> <a/> <b/> </parent>`, then you can select `b` based on that it is a sibling of the `a` before it, but you can’t select `a` based on that it is followed by `b`.

Comment: any workaround? @Quentin

Comment: @rony36 — Add a class to the element.

Comment: yeah I thought that at the first place. but it's a plugin `trumbowyg` quite difficult (or I don't know how to) to add class to the element :( @Quentin

Comment: Anyways, thanks everyone, to confirm me that "It's not possible" :)